# Strings: Reference variables in Java

Tags: java

Yes, this is a basic point of confusion that has been discussed before, but there's a lot of convoluted information and I'm hoping that someone can pinpoint my exact misunderstanding here.

```
public class Test {
  public static void change(int i) {
    i = 2;
  }
  public static void change(int[] i) {
    i[0] = 6;
  }
  public static void change(String i) {
    i = "Bye";
  }
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int a = 1;
    int[] b = {3,4,5};
    String c = "Hello";
    change(a);
    change(b);
    change(c);
    System.out.println(a);    // 1 - value unchanged
    System.out.println(b[0]); // 6 - value changed
    System.out.println(c);    // Hello - value unchanged
  }
}
```

1. The variable `a` *actually contains* the value 1. When we pass this to the `change()` method, a new variable is created, which *also* contains the value 1. Thus when we change `i`, `a` is unaffected. This makes sense.
2. The variable `c` contains a *reference* to an array object in memory. When we pass this to the `change()` method, a new variable is created, which contains the same reference. Thus, they both represent the same object. So when we change `i[0]`, `c[0]` is also changed. This also makes sense.
3. What I'm having trouble with is if Strings are just object references in Java, why do they behave like primitives in this regard?

Comment: `i = "Bye";` Changes only the object reference stored in the `i` variable...

Comment: Don't confuse mutating an object with modifying a variable.

Comment: You're comparing apples to oranges - your array function doesn't assign to the parameter but to an element in the array that the parameter refers to.